# git delete a file for a dev branch and keep it into the master branch

Tags: git

I have my branch master with 10 files and i commit it.

Next i would have a branch dev with only 1 file

How do you delete the files from the dev branch without loose the files from 
the master branch ?

I'm a beginner in git.

Thanks.

Comment: If you delete the files on the 'dev' branch, it doesn't affect your 'master' branch until you merge 'dev' in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete files from your `dev` branch without affecting your `master` branch.

First switch to your `dev` branch:

```
git checkout dev
```

Then, delete the files using Git:

```
git rm file1.txt
git rm file2.txt
```

Finally, commit your changes:

```
git commit -m "deleted a few files"
```

Comment: Thank you. :-) and have a nice day